# Application has been blocked from accessing graphics hardware issue with CS:GO

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

The only game that this happens in is Counter-Strike: Global Offensive. It will randomly do it whenever I am playing. It's not at a specific time. My temperatures are normal. (34C) Any help?

Here are my specs:

[image]

> error: CSGO.exe has been blocked from accessing graphics hardware.

It will grey screen my CS:GO and I can't play CS:GO again until I restart my computer, but then it will do it again the next time I play so it's a never-ending loop. My system does indeed exceed the system requirements, and this has only been happening ever since I installed Windows 10.

Comment: What will it do exactly?  If you are getting an error, provide us the exact message within the body of the question, so your question is clear.

Comment: Application has been blocked from accessing graphics hardware issue with cs go. It's the title but I'll add it to the body of the message.

Comment: You have the current drivers for your Intel/Nvidia/AMD GPU installed?  Your system meets or exceeds the requirements for the program your running?

Comment: Of course, this has been happening ever since I have gotten windows 10 btw. I'll put that in body of question. and yes, my specs greatly exceeds the requirements.